# Special Characters Not Working in Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm Currently putting together all my work and I opened an old program I had written for console in VS2012 C++. Everything Still works fine but the special characters I used for things like the suits are not showing properly. I wrote the program in vs2012 but I am now using vs2015 as well as making the move from windows 8 to windows 10. All i can find anywhere is that there is some setting somewhere but i don't know what that setting is or where it is. Any help would be great thanks.

```
return 03; // Heart
return 04; // Diamond
return 05; // Club
return 06; // Spade
```

this i what use to work to output the characters but now it outputs a box in a box for all 4.

There was a question a while back that says to check in the properties "use old console but i cannot find that option in VS 2015

Comment: Nobody can see your code. Why do you bother asking a question at all?

Comment: The code is fine its just the some settings within windows or VS i need help finding hoping that someone on her has come across a similar issue

Comment: Ive also now added a small example of my problem